# Why is it that $E(xy) = E(x)E(y)$ if $x$ and $y$ are uncorrelated random variables?

Tags: probability

Also, why does $E(xy) = E(x)E(y)$ not hold if $x$ and $y$ are correlated? Perhaps at a more basic, intuitive level, what's the difference between $E(xy)$ and $E(x)E(y)$?

Comment: Small correction. If $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, but not necessarily independent.

Comment: Oh! Since then, their covariance is 0. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is that we say that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated _exactly when_ $E[XY]$ happens to equal $E[X]E[Y]$, and if $E[XY] \neq E[X]E[Y]$ then we do not say that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated random variables; we say that they are _correlated_ random variables.

Answer (score 19):

Where $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables, by definition they are independent when $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Then we have$$\begin{align}E(XY)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{XY}(x,y)xydxdy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(y)xydxdy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)xdx\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)ydy \\
&=E(X)E(Y)
\end{align}$$

The proof in the discrete case is analogous. This shows why independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$. The converse does not necessarily hold—that is, we can come up with examples of random variables $X,Y$ with $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ but which are not independent. Whenever $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$, $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated *by definition*: $$\text{Cov}(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]=0\implies E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$$

Comment: Thank you! So you group terms into 2 integrals because y's terms are not dependent on x's integral and vice versa please?

Comment: A bit late, but yes you can split up 2D integrals when the function is separable.